# How to specify ids for navbar style

Tags: html, css

I've glommed together a navbar with its own stylesheet, that works approximately like I want it to.  If I uncomment the links to stylesheets for bootstrap, however, many of its properties are overridden. Most noticeably is that the menu items are now in separate rows instead of the same.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Navbar Test</title>

<h1>Navbar Test</h1>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="navbartest.css">

<nav class="navbar">  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav left-links">
    <li><a class="links" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown links">
      <span>Menu 1</span>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown links">
      <span>Menu 2</span>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown links">
      <span>Menu 3</span>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav right-links">
    <li class="dropdown links">
      <span>Welcome Brian</span>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">User Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!--
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">
</head>
-->
```

And here is the stylesheet, navbartest.css:

```
html { font-family: sans-serif; background: #eee; padding: 1rem; }
body { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background: white; }
h1 { font-family: serif; color: #377ba8; margin: 1rem 0; }
a { color: #377ba8; }
hr { border: none; border-top: 1px solid lightgray; }

body{
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:60px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.selected{
   border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}


.content { padding: 0 1rem 1rem; }
.content > header { border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; }
.content > header h1 { flex: auto; margin: 1rem 0 0.25rem 0; }
.flash { margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em; background: #cae6f6; border: 1px solid #377ba8; }
.post > header { display: flex; align-items: flex-end; font-size: 0.85em; }
.post > header > div:first-of-type { flex: auto; }
.post > header h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.post .about { color: slategray; font-style: italic; }
.post .body { white-space: pre-line; }
.content:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
.content form { margin: 1em 0; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.content label { font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
.content input, .content textarea { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.content textarea { min-height: 12em; resize: vertical; }
input.danger { color: #cc2f2e; }
input[type=submit] { align-self: start; min-width: 10em; }

nav { background: slategray; display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 0 0.5rem; }
nav h1 { flex: auto; margin: 0; }
nav h1 a { text-decoration: none; padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem; }
nav ul  { display: flex; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
nav ul li a, nav ul li span, header .action { display: block; padding: 0.5rem; }

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.left-links{
   flex:1 1 200px;
}
.links {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px;
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: bolder;
}
.links:hover {
   border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}
```

I'm aware that the solution is to [increase CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).  I'm not sure how to do that.  If I want to give it the navbar an identifier like "my-navbar" so that the stylesheet doesn't get overridden, where exactly do I need to make those changes?

Comment: where is you CSS included? It should be listed at the bottom of all CSS links. otherwise an easy approach to raise the specificity weight is to use the style attribtue in the ehad element which has a specificity weight heigher then CSS and lower then inline-style. Otherwise you can use an id to the navbar and use `nav#id` as selector which would gain a very high specificity within CSS.

Comment: The end result is made using macros in jinja, so I don't think I can easily change the order of the CSS files.  Adding the id to the navbar is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Either here or in an answer, can you be explicit about the changes that need to be made to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `<nav class="navbar">` use `<nav id="navbar">`. An id has a higher specificity weight then a class. Then for every single CSS line that effect the navbar start with `nav#navbar` as it raises the specificty weight. The specificity level within the same category (!important; > inline-stye > head-style > CSS) is:

`tag#id` > `tag.class` > `#id` > `.class` > `tag`

So if every CSS Selector start with `nav#navbar` it will already outwieght every framework seelctor that only target tags or classes.

Comment: Following this to the best of my ability didn't solve the problem, but it's well explained and should help folks in the future!  I ended up figuring out an alternate fix  (removing navbar-nav class from the first list of links) so I won't pursue the issue further for the moment.